# can i access a web server via virtual block in enginx?

Tags: azure, vpn, vps, octoprint

so Im not sure how to describe it. I want to access my octoprint server via my personal website as a subdomain or direcotry. I am running nginx on an ubuntu 14.5.2 server on a VPS. The octoprint servers connects directly to the VPS via VPN.

Im sorry the title isn't that clear I'm not sure how to describe my goal.

All I need is a point in the right direction. If you want to write a full tutorial be my guest. But any documentation will do. I can figure it out when I know exactly what I need to look for.

Answer (score 1):

**AWW!** how could i be so ***stupid!*** i just need to use a ***reverse proxy***!

I am kicking my self right now.